# Mibble MIB Parser - extracting comments from the mib

Tags: java, snmp, asn.1, oid

I am using the [Mibble MIB Parser](http://www.mibble.org/) to extract all simple data types from an MIB file. I've been successful until my attempt to extract comment text.

Take the following module as an example:

```
invBookList OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  INTEGER {
                    mobydick(1),     -- call me ishmael 
                    paradiselost(2), -- aComment
                    1984(3),         -- aComment
                    solaris(4)       -- aComment
            }
    MAX-ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS          current
    DESCRIPTION
            "A few Books for an example."
    ::= { invMasterList 43 }
```

According to Mibble's API, the OBJECT-TYPE can be accessed by extracting an SnmpObjectType and then calling the appropriate getter method. Which I have done, and can successfully extract all of the text ***except the comments in the INTEGER syntax.***

I have tried calling getSyntax().getComment() on the SnmpObjectType, but always returns null. getSyntax() will extract the INTEGER syntax, e.g.:

```
mobydick(1),paradiselist(2),1984(3),solaris(4)
```

but unfortunately strips out the comments.

Any one out there have experience with Mibble Parser who knows how to extract the comments?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use version 2.9 of Mibble. Then look into MibWriter.java to understand how to use the API:

https://github.com/cederberg/mibble/blob/master/src/java/net/percederberg/mibble/MibWriter.java